# Xamarin Forms Android app crashes in Release for few devices

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a simple Xamarin Forms app which after upgrading started crashing in Release mode for Pixel 3 emulator, however, its working fine Amazon Fire tab and Xolo Era 3 devices.

I found following error in logcat -

> l_3_pie_9_0_-_api_28  Error   13193   DEBUG   Abort message:
>   'java_vm_ext.cc:545] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION:
>   CallStaticIntMethodV received NULL jclass'
>       eax 00000000  ebx 00003377  ecx 00003377  edx 00000006

Another thing to notice is when I upgraded Xamarin Forms and Xamarin Essentials it gave me an error that `Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter` NuGet package is missing. I explicitly installed it and the error went away.

Following are the environment and upgrade details - 
[image]

[image]

Thanks for your help.

**Update -** 
Only external library I am using is `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads`

Link to [Xamarin Community question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/179595/xamarin-forms-android-app-crashes-in-release-for-few-devices)

Comment: You could add a check for null values. And check with other emulator, if the other emulators works well, you could try to reinstall the SDK of Android.

Comment: Reinstalling SDK did the trick. Thanks @WendyZang-MSFT please write this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this error, you could try to reinstall the SDK of Android.